# Is there a code coverage tool built-in in Bluemix?

Tags: code-coverage, ibm-cloud, devops

Is there a code coverage tool built-in in Bluemix? Say, I am writing Java code and want to get the code coverage being reported. Do I need to use something like SonarCube? Or is there something built in?

Answer (score 1):

There is not such a specific built-in tool in the catalog. You should use something locally for this purpose.
Anyway you might take a look at Devops services offer in the catalog, even though it doesn't fit exactly with your request:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/?search=devops

Comment: One up for the first sentence. The rest is low value. Thanks.